# daylight saving time influences the result of mktime

Tags: awk, timezone, dst

I have an issue trying to get the exact GPS time. Looks like the issue is related to command `mktime` used in the code.
To get the correct GPS time I have added -2 hrs in UTC.

But the purpose is to have a code to calculate the GPS time automatically and don't use manually changes at UTC-2 as an example

**Input file GMT time ( > 3 hrs in local time )**

```
18/05/21 08:18:29
18/05/21 08:20:25
18/05/21 08:21:02
```

When I run the code below, got 1 hour less :

```
gawk -F'[/: ]' -v ts=$(date -d'01/06/1980' +%s)  \
                -v lap=18 '{$1="" d=sprintf(20$0); 
                            print mktime(d)+lap-ts }'  file
```

**result output GPS TIME ( < 1 hr )**

```
1210922327
1210922443
1210922480
```

When I run the code below, got exactly the correct GPS time.

```
gawk -F'[/: ]' -v ts=$(TZ=UTC-2 date -d'1/6/1980 0:00' +%s)  \
                -v lap=18 '{$1="" d=sprintf(20$0); 
                            print mktime(d)+lap-ts }' file
```

**Result output GPS TIME ( exactly time: OUTPUT DESIRED)**

```
1210925927
1210926043
1210926080
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `mktime` expects an input of the form "YYYY MM DD hh mm ss". So everything is space delimited and there are no special characters such as "-" or "/" or "T" or "." or ":"

Comment: Hi kvantor in the input file is the information for mktime ( 18/05/21 08:18:29 )

Comment: Hi OXXO, as I indicated in the previous comment, `mktime` cannot interpret such format, you need to convert it from `18/05/21 08:18:29` into `2018 05 21 08 18 29` only then you will receive the correct seconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00`. You can do something like `d=$0; gsub(/[/:]/," ",d); mktime("20"d);`

Comment: kvantor, it works the only issue i have is the problem of one hr less, that i believe is because mktime.

Comment: In december 2017 it works perfectly, but now it have the issue of < 1 hr?.

Comment: ￼ Daylight saving time?

Comment: how it affects ? how to avoid it?

Comment: _[**`mktime(datespec [, utc-flag ])`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) :: `datespec` is of the form `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"` If the `DST` daylight-savings flag is positive, the time is assumed to be daylight savings time; if zero, the time is assumed to be standard time; and if **negative (the default)**, `mktime()` attempts to determine whether daylight savings time is in effect for the specified time._ So I suggest to add an extra `0` behind it.

Comment: Eveything depends on your systems timezone (`TZ`) probably in December, your timezone was set to `UTC-3` and now it is `UTC-2` that is why you have the hour difference. If your times represent pure `UTC` times, then you should indicate this clearly to `mktime` or do `export TZ="UTC"` before issuing `awk`

Comment: Kvantor, kindly can you explain how to do export TZ=UTC where it will located in the code.. Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are encountering is mostly related to the time-zone settings of your system. Due to [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), your time-zone shifted one hour which causes the discrepancy. A very nice post of detecting DST, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42999971/8344060). Copying its examples, we can show that for the time-zone *TZ=Europe/Stockholm*, the time-zone changes to summer time depending on the date :

```
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm date +%Z # CET or CEST depending of when its run
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm date --date=20170101 +%Z # CET
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm date --date=20170601 +%Z # CEST
$ TZ=CET date --date=20170101 +%Z # CET
$ TZ=CET date --date=20170601 +%Z # CEST, note that its auto adjusted to CEST
```

and therefore it will for sure have an effect on the epoch time which is given from *1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC*. With `zdump` we see when DST comes into affect :

```
$ zdump -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm | grep 2018
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm  Sun Mar 25 00:59:59 2018 UTC = Sun Mar 25 01:59:59 2018 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm  Sun Mar 25 01:00:00 2018 UTC = Sun Mar 25 03:00:00 2018 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm  Sun Oct 28 00:59:59 2018 UTC = Sun Oct 28 02:59:59 2018 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm  Sun Oct 28 01:00:00 2018 UTC = Sun Oct 28 02:00:00 2018 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
```

and this is seen in the epoch time  as :

```
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm date -d "2018-03-25 01:59:59" +%s
1521939599
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm date -d "2018-03-25 03:00:00" +%s
1521939600
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm date -d "2018-03-25 02:00:00" +%s
date: invalid date ‘2018-03-25 02:00:00’
```

As you see, for *TZ=Europe/Stockholm*, the time *2018-03-25T02:00:00* does not exist and the other two are only 1 sec apart.

---

**Summary, what does this all mean:** it essentially means that your system automatically compensates for DST, unless your TZ is UTC. And this play a role on all date related command such as `systime()`, `date` or even Awk's `mktime()`.

---

**Can we avoid DST compensation with `awk`:** 
Since the OP wants the GPS-time, i.e. the total seconds since 1980-01-06T00:00:00, you essentially subtract two times. So if both are computed in the same TZ without DST correction, you always get the correct result. There are 2 ways to do this :

- **execute your command in a specific timezone**:
  By forcing the system to work in a single TZ (such as UTC, UTC+2, ...), there will be no DST correction. For the OP's question, the TZ of interest is UTC.

  ```
  $ TZ="UTC" awk 'BEGIN { ts  = mktime("1980 01 06 00 00 00") }
                  { datespec="20"$0; gsub(/[/:]/," ",datespec);
                    print mktime(datespec) + lap - ts
                  }' lap=18 file
  ```

  or from `awk 4.20` onwards you can tell `mktime()` to assume that the date is in UTC by using the UTC flag. (`mktime(datespec [, utc-flag ])`)

  ```
  $ awk 'BEGIN { ts  = mktime("1980 01 06 00 00 00",1) }
         { datespec="20"$0; gsub(/[/:]/," ",datespec);
           print mktime(datespec,1) + lap - ts
         }' lap=18 file
  ```

  both result in the following output.

  ```
  1210925927
  1210926043
  1210926080
  ```

  In both cases, you don't need to worry about your system-timezone and all the mumbo-jumbo related to daylight savings time.
- **disable DST correction with `mktime`**: When adding a `DST` entry to the `datespec` part of `mktime`, you can tell the system to alwyas work in DST or not or let the system figure it out by himself. The latter is what you do **not** want. `datespec` is a string of the form `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]`. And this brings it down too:

  ```
  $ awk 'BEGIN { ts  = mktime("1980 01 06 00 00 00 0") }
         { datespec="20"$0; gsub(/[/:]/," ",datespec);
           print mktime(datespec" 0") + lap - ts
         }' lap=18 file
  ```

---

Documentation for `mktime` awk 4.2.0 onwards:

> [**`mktime(datespec [, utc-flag ])`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)
>   Turn `datespec` into a timestamp in the same form as is returned by `systime()`. It is similar to the function of the same name in ISO C. The argument, `datespec`, is a string of the form `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"`. The string consists of six or seven numbers representing, respectively, the full year including century, the month from 1 to 12, the day of the month from 1 to 31, the hour of the day from 0 to 23, the minute from 0 to 59, the second from 0 to 60,55 and an optional daylight-savings flag.
>
> The values of these numbers need not be within the ranges specified; for example, an hour of -1 means 1 hour before midnight. The origin-zero Gregorian calendar is assumed, with year 0 preceding year 1 and year -1 preceding year 0. **If `utc-flag` is present and is either non-zero or non-null, the time is assumed to be in the UTC time zone; otherwise, the time is assumed to be in the local time zone.** If the `DST` daylight-savings flag is positive, the time is assumed to be daylight savings time; if zero, the time is assumed to be standard time; and if negative (the default), `mktime()` attempts to determine whether daylight savings time is in effect for the specified time.
>
> If `datespec` does not contain enough elements or if the resulting time is out of range, `mktime()` returns `-1`.

Comment: Kvantour, amazing explanation. tks a lot for this, I have modified in my output the results as I noticed one extra digit now the results matches with the output from your code. Many tks again for the extensive information and excellent code.

Comment: @OXXO I have rewritten the post, believing that the solution is in there. I hope this helps. Please remove some of the comments here as they do not contribute to the post anymore and all issues you presented have been resolved.

Comment: Hi Kvantour, it is a very good explanation about the Daylight Saving Time, and how it affects to the mktime functions, really appreciate you share of this information, will be very useful for other users. I use the option  to force the system to work in a single TZ, it works perfectly now. Thanks again for very useful post.