# How to make CronJob respect daylight saving time?

Tags: kubernetes, cron

Let's say I and the partner company I'm dealing with live in a country that employs [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

I have a CronJob in a kubernetes cluster that uploads files to the partner company daily at, say, 4:00, 10:00, 16:00, and 22:00. E.g. `0 4,10,16,22 * * *`.

Kubernetes SIG [decided](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47202#issuecomment-360820586) that CronJob object will not support local timezone and will always run in the default one, which is UTC.

I can change the schedule, so that it reflects local time specified above in UTC and give the CronJob that schedule. However every time daylight saving kicks in (twice a year) I would need somehow modify all the CronJobs to use the new time, *and* I need to modify my deployment pipeline to create new releases of the CronJobs with the new time.

I cannot keep the CronJob running on the same schedule past daylight saving change, as the job will upload files not during the times expected by the partner.

What is the easiest way to manage this?

**Option 1**

It was [suggested](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47202#issuecomment-400421237) that writing a new kubernetes controller could do, but it does not seem that anyone raised up to that challenge and published working solution.

**Option 2**

Another option I have considered is changing the timezone of the entire cluster. But if you [google it](https://www.google.com/search?&q=kubernetes+cluster+change+timezone) it does not seem to be very popular solution, and some people strongly believe that kubernetes being a cloud application should be run in UTC.

From what I understand `cron` uses a local time zone which, in case of kubernetes will be the timezone of the controller manager, which is not necessary a timezone of the node it is running on. On the other hand, changing time zone of the controller manager container, sounds risky, as it is not clear how it will interact with other components of the kubernetes, such as etcd and kubelets.

**Option 3**

Doing it manually twice a year. Since people in the organisation come and go it would be difficult to retain the knowledge when and how. I do not want our partner to complain twice a year. Also it might be tricky to set up notifications for this as the dates change every year.

**Option 4**

Write some homegrown automation to run twice a year and hope that when time comes it works as expected. That is actually triggers, triggers at the right time and does everything it's supposed to do. (the latter is easier to test but the former is harder).

All these options feel quite unsatisfactory. I googled a lot and I have not found a lot, I feel it should be quite common issue, and yet nothing comes up in the search. Am I overlooking something? Is there an easy and natural way to solve it?

Comment: Option 2 i.e. follow the UTC settings while working on solutions which require such time coordination. Save yourself from one nitty-gritty to worry about when the time either moves fwd/backward in your case

Comment: @RaunakJhawar I have very low confidence that it would work, since I have not found any reports that it ever worked for anyone for a production-like environment for a decent interval of time and there are a lot of moving parts.

Comment: There is no natural way to make cron tabs respect DST if UTC is not adopted.

Comment: Someone wrote this: https://github.com/hiddeco/cronjobber

Comment: The comments around just using UTC are incorrect when humans are involved and they work with localtime, eg a cron job to send an email report at 8am in the morning. One workaround I have is that I've modified my cron job to trigger a bash script every hour, and IF the expected local time is correct (6am EST for example) then I trigger the expected job after that, otherwise the script just exits.

Comment: There is a proposal to [support timezones for cronjobs](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-apps/19-Graduate-CronJob-to-Stable#support-timezone-for-cronjobs) which may solve this issue in future.

Comment: @Matt it does not look like it [materialized](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47202#issuecomment-824371489)

Answer (score 1):

Time Zones was added to CronJob in Kubernetes 1.22. To cite [github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47202#issuecomment-950887675)

> Just to clarify, it's available in 1.22.

> It was implemented in a very strange way that's not exposed in the schema, though. I'm not aware of any explanation for why that was done, and it ignores core concepts behind Kubernetes. I think this still needs work.

It can be done via `CRON_TZ` variable, as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/release-1.22/content/en/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs.md).

```
#      ┌────────────────── timezone (optional)
#      |      ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
#      |      │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
#      |      │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
#      |      │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
#      |      │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
#      |      │ │ │ │ │                                   7 is also Sunday on some systems)
#      |      │ │ │ │ │
#      |      │ │ │ │ │
# CRON_TZ=UTC * * * * *
```

**Update**

This feature is to be marked as [unsupported](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/104404#issuecomment-970406114)

**Update**

Since Kubernetes 1.27 time zones in CronJobs are now [supported](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#time-zones).

```
kind: CronJob
apiVersion: batch/v1
metadata:
  name: myCronjob
spec:
  schedule: "10 1 * * *"
  timeZone: Pacific/Auckland
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          name: myCronjob
          labels:
            app: myCronjob
        spec:
...
```

Comment: This defines the timezone for which the controller works. This will not solve the DST problem unless it accepts values as 'Europe/Vienna' for example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but argo workflows has a Cron Workflows CRD that supports timezones and daylight saving. https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/cron-workflows/#daylight-saving.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I come a bit late to the party, but I believe that the easiest is to have two cronjobs running in combination with a `tz-check`. When the time-zone matches the expected value, only then run `command`

A very nice post of detecting [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42999971/8344060). Copying its examples, we can show that for the time-zone *TZ=Europe/Stockholm*, the time-zone changes to summer time depending on the date :

```
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm date +%Z # CET or CEST depending of when its run
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm date --date=20170101 +%Z # CET
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm date --date=20170601 +%Z # CEST
$ TZ=CET date --date=20170101 +%Z # CET
$ TZ=CET date --date=20170601 +%Z # CEST, note that its auto adjusted to CEST
```

So, when staying in this example and assume the OP wants to run his cron on different times depending on if we are in DST or not, we could write the following crontab:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .--------------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |    .---------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |    |     .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |    |     |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |    |     |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |    |     |  |  |
# command only runs in Europe/Stockholm Winter time
  0  4-23/6  *  *  *   tz-test "Europe/Stockholm" "CET"  && command
# command only runs in Europe/Stockholm Summer time
  0  3-23/6  *  *  *   tz-test "Europe/Stockholm" "CEST" && command
```

Here, the times in the crontab definition are given in UTC (as the cron runs in UTC) and the `tz-test` command is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tz=$(TZ="$1" date "+%Z")
[ "$tz" == "$2" ]
```

**Note:** You still have to be careful here. It might be possible that, due to the time-selection, your crontab runs twice or even more on the day the hour changes. In the above example, this is not the case.

**Note:** while this question was for Kubernetes, I'm convinced a similar implementation can be achieved within that framework.

Comment: `while this question was for Kubernetes, I'm convinced a similar implementation can be achieved within that framework` It seems to be a bit unfounded. The whole problem was with how CronJob Controller is implemented, not at pod/OS level. They did some changes to improve this recently, [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69904674/284111)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [kubernetes 1.24/1.25](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#time-zones) there is a feature gate `CronJobTimeZone` that allows you to set `.spec.timeZone` to the name of a valid [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). For example, setting `.spec.timeZone`: "Etc/UTC" instructs Kubernetes to interpret the schedule relative to Coordinated Universal Time. The feature gate is disabled by default in version 1.24 and enabled by default in version 1.25