# Batch change accessed and modified date, with date from another file's content?

Tags: bash, macos, date

I'm migrating old notes from a SQL database based note taking app to separate text files.
I've managed to export the notes and date codes as separate text files.

The files are ordered like this:

```
$ ls -1
Note0001.txt
Note0001-date.txt
Note0002.txt
Note0002-date.txt
Note0003.txt
Note0003-date.txt
```

The contents of the date files looks like this:

```
$ cat Note0001-date.txt 
388766121.742373
$ cat Note0002-date.txt 
274605766.273638
$ cat Note0003-date.txt 
384996285.436197
```

The dates are seconds since the epoch 2001-01-01. See other question about the format: [What type of date format is this? And how to convert it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605470/).

How do I batch change the accessed and modified date of the notes files, NoteNNNN.txt, to the date in the contents of respective date file, NoteNNNN-date.txt?

How to convert the date to UTC+1? Preferably with consideration of DST (daylight saving time).
I am trying to convert the dates with the method described this question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/
But it outputs an error message in bash 3.2.57 (macOS):

```
$ date -d '2001-01-01 UTC+1 + 388766121 seconds'
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
        [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

I am new to working with the dates and timestamps in the terminal.

Comment: You want [to touch](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) the files.

Comment: . `What date format is that` ? You just specified that `The dates are seconds since the epoch 2001-01-01` so they are in seconds since epoch. In what format are they? `how to convert it?` What is "it" in that sentence and convert to what? Convert a "date format"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited that.

Comment: Is your box timezone UTC+1? `date +%Z` =?

Comment: Yes my timezone i UTC+1 (Sweden) with DST during the summer. date +%Z gives CEST.

Comment: That's good, then both `date` (and the `awk strftime`) should print CEST by default. You don't have to worry for the timezone output.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each file pair, access the timestamp, shift the timestamp so it's something unix tools can understand, then touch files. Ie. big problems are composed of sum of small problems.

```
# find all files named .txt but not -date.txt
find . -name '*.txt' '!' -name '*-date.txt' |
# remove the .txt suffix
sed 's/\.txt$//' |
{ 
   # the reference point of files content
   start=$(date -d "2001-01-01" +%s) # will not work with BSD date
   # I guess just precompute the value:
   start=978303600
   # for each file
   while IFS= read -r f; do
       # get the timestamp
       diff=$(<"$f"-date.txt)
       # increment the timestamp to seconds since epoch
       ref=$(<<<"scale=6; $start + $diff" bc)
       # TODO: use a tool convert the timestamp sinece epoch to BSD touch 
       # compatible format, ie. to ccyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS[.frac][Z]
       ref=(TODO "$ref")
       # change access and modification times of .txt file
       touch -d "@$ref" "$f".txt
   done
}
```

Comment: Thanks KamilCuk. Will that script also respect UTC+1 and DST?

Comment: I tested the script and it shows an error:
touch: illegal option -- d

Comment: `Will that script also respect UTC+1 and DST?` No idea, see `man date` for hanlding of `LC_*` and `TZ` environment variables. `touch: illegal option -- d` och right, you are on macos. So you have openbsd [touch](https://man.openbsd.org/touch.1) and [date](https://man.openbsd.org/date.1), I wrote that with GNU tools in mind. You could install GNU alternatives or refactor the script to something BSD touch and date can work with.

Comment: If you use **homebrew** on **macOS**, you can run `brew install coreutils` and that will give you GNU `date` and `touch` as `gdate` and `gtouch`. HTH.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Mark. I changed to gdate and gtouch in the first version of KamilCuk's script and it worked on macOS.
But I still don't know how to handle UTC+1 and DST. Some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901906/, but there might be a better way.
Really close now.

Comment: `how to handle UTC+1 and DST` How do you want to "handle it" exactly? What is there to "handle"?

Comment: During DST the time should be plus one hour, or UTC+2 instead of normal UTC+1. I checked the dates modified by the script and it does not adjust for this. So some files that are close to midnight gets the wrong date.

Comment: I just verified this by making a new entry in the db and transferred the db to the Mac and repeated the date conversion process with @KamilCuk s script. The time was off by one hour, in other words DST was not respected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your OS local timezone is what you want for your output, and you have a version of `awk` that supports the [GNU awk time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html), you could use the
following script. Also:

> If the DST daylight-savings flag is positive, the time is assumed to
> be daylight savings time; if zero, the time is assumed to be standard
> time; and if negative (**the default**), mktime() attempts to determine
> whether daylight savings time is in effect for the specified time.

file `tst.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    epoch = mktime("2001 01 01 00 00 00") 
}

FNR==1 {
    close(out)
    out = substr(FILENAME, 1, length(FILENAME)-9) ".txt"
}

{ 
    print strftime("%F %T %Z", epoch+$0) > out
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f tst.awk *-date.txt
```

---

**Example**

Here is an example with the script, without the I/O part, just converting the datetimes.

test file:

```
> cat file
388766121.742373
274605766.273638
384996285.436197
```

script `tst.awk`:

```
BEGIN { epoch = mktime("2001 01 01 00 00 00") }
{ print strftime("%F %T %Z", epoch+$0) }
```

Output:

```
> awk -f tst.awk file
2013-04-27 15:35:21 EEST
2009-09-14 08:22:46 EEST
2013-03-14 23:24:45 EET
```

The timezone of my box is being used by default (EET). If we 'd like to print to a different timezone, we should define that and set the `TZ`. Also DST is used by default, notice that some days are printed as EEST (Summer Time).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tested it and got this:  
`$ awk -f epoch-2001-convert.awk *-date.txt
awk: can't open file epoch-2001-convert.awk
 source line number 1 source file epoch-2001-convert.awk
 context is
  >>>  <<<`

Comment: How do I print the DST flag?

Comment: @Kasam I have updated with a **example** to demonstate what I said and that DST is by default on. If you get any error like `awk: can't open file...` that's on you to resolve it, the error message is very clear.

Comment: The problem was awk on macOS, after installing brew gawk the scripts worked. When running the first script on a file named MemoLite0142.txt it created a file named MemoLit.txt with a timestamp. The timestamp had wrong date, but correct [!] time adjusted for DST. 
The modified script printed to screen. Same result as above, wrong date, but correct time. 
How can this method be used to change files timestamp [with correct date]?

Comment: @Kasam is there a standard offset diff between results and expected dates, for all conversions? How many days is it?

Comment: @thabasisp the date printed by the script is the base date: `2001-01-01`

Comment: Please run this example: `echo "388766121.742373" | awk 'BEGIN { epoch = mktime("2001 01 01 00 00 00") } { print strftime("%F %T %Z", epoch+$0) }'` . Does it print date `2013-04-27` ?

Comment: Yes. Even with normal awk. It prints `2013-04-27 15:35:21 CEST`.

Comment: So the conversion is OK, your environment (macOS) is updated and OK. Your input file should contain only one timestamp per line, no other characters, no other text lines, or for anything else it is expected to print 2001, that's the epoch plus zero. I hope you can go on with it now.

Comment: I don't have a clue how to go on from now. I am not used to working with timestamps. How can the output be used as a timestamp? Does your script work as a batch process?

Comment: Yes it works. Assuming that your case of inputs is exactly what you have described in your question. But if input files are not exactly like this, I cannot know. In any case: **The scipt in the example (2 lines long) can convert a file with one date per row.**

Comment: Hi again, I've been experimenting with this again. And your script converts the date format, but it writes it to NoteNNNN.txt and thus overwrites its contents. I want the converted date to be written to the files date modified (and date created).